# Grok testing not working for me?

Tags: regex, debugging, logstash-grok, grok

I'm trying to test out something using the grok debugger and I'm not having a ton of luck.

I have the following input:

```
?brandingMediaId=1
```

And I want to match the entire string that starts with a ? until the first space after it, so I'm using

```
%{\?[^\s]+:TEST}
```

As a custom pattern and the trying to match %{TEST:mytest} and I'm getting a compile error.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

**EDIT:  I'm dumb:  I didn't know that %URIPARAM is a thing.  I'm going to close this in a moment.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches a pattern called %{URIPARAM} which can be used like %{URIPARAM:HttpParam} or something like that.